# How do I save the pretty lady?

Tags: brothers-tale-of-two-sons

I'm having trouble in chapter five (the giant's battleground) where I come upon a tribe of ritualistic warriors.  I figure that I have to draw them away, then hide in the image while they run off the cliff.  Once they're all gone, I presume that I save the pretty lady.  My problem is that I can't seem to draw them down the stairs.  I've made a short YouTube video to better illustrate my problem:

They always come as far as the stairs, but never down them.  If I manage to attract all of them at once, then inevitably, one of the the brothers dies due to my lack of coordination for controlling both of them at once.  I already know how to hide in the drawing at the bottom landing, so I figure that's key to passing this area, but if I do get into hiding position, the tribesmen just stand there doing nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look closely. Before you walk up the stairs to the ceremony, there's a flow of blood running around an obelisk. Notice that there's a figure of two *red* people standing upon each other (the hiding spot you mentioned).

So get yourself completely red, and have the brothers act as the tribesmen's god. Hint: you can walk with the older brother while holding up the younger one.

Comment: There's also a nice hint right before you get to the area.

Comment: @Bonnici: Yes, right after you walked through the stream of blood. I had actually recorded that part with ShadowPlay, but there was a bug and all that was left in the recording was a green screen :/